# Windows 8.1 Universal Store App connect to COM port

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serial-port, windows-store-apps

I'm currently writing a code in C# that would allow the user to read from the usb COM port (I currently have a microcontroller feeding it constant values to the usb port through serial print) and print it to the output of visual studio.

I've been reading up on a lot of documentation, specifically the MS's guide to conecting to USB: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn312121.aspx#step1 
but I'm now finding that the USB device isn't supported.
However, would it be possible to simply read from the Serial port instead of entirely connecting the USB device to the project?

Since it's a Store App, I can't use Serial.IO.Ports

Comment: Just want to point out that I've been using [Serial Port access for Metro Style App](http://ioi.solutions/serial-port-access-metro-style-app/) for reference, which isn't what I'm exactly looking for but does something similar